# Axios get request keeps hitting 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

This is the get request:

`this.props.userId` contains the userId.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/auth/booked/' + this.props.userId)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

This is the routes on my backend:

`router.get('/booked:id', UserController.bookedClasses);`

It's something to do with the `'/booked:id'`

Result:

`GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/booked/5bdb18071c8fb30d31969aef 404 (Not Found)`

Nice and simple but for some odd reason, I can't get a response, I have all my system working apart from this route, can anyone spot anything that shouldn't be there?

Any feedback would be appreciated to help me and others!

This is my routes folder which holds all my routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const UserController = require('../controllers/auth');

router.post('', UserController.createUser);

router.post('/login', UserController.login);

router.post('/bookclass', UserController.bookClass);

router.get('/:id', UserController.getUser);

router.get('/booked:id', UserController.bookedClasses);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Maybe  router.get('/booked:id', UserController.bookedClasses); should be router.get('/booked/:id', UserController.bookedClasses);

Comment: It's because your route should be `router.get('/booked/:id', UserController.bookedClasses);`

Comment: Sorted, it was the `'/booked/:id'` missed the `/`. Can someone make an answer out of this so we can help others who might hit an issue like this, always good to help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Router params must be specified in the path of the route. Example:

```
'/some/route/:param'
```

or with multiple params:

```
'/some/route/:param/:anotherParam'
```

In your example:

```
router.get('/booked:id', UserController.bookedClasses);
```

should be (check the extra / in the path):

```
router.get('/booked/:id', UserController.bookedClasses);
```